# Child Products appearance for different websites in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, multi-website

I have 2 websites "Retail" and "Wholesale". I am using configurable products on both the sites.
For each configurable products, some child products are to be shown on Retail site and some on Wholesale site.
See https://prnt.sc/um8eyp

Now in frontend when i visit the retail and the wholesale website all the 3 child products are visible there.
In fact, i have selected proper website scope for them.
See https://prnt.sc/um8flv for 50 yards roll products which need to be visible only on wholesale site
See https://prnt.sc/um8fsz for yards product  which needs to be visible on retail site.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Have to take a look at admin. If you are able to share admin access i can take a look.

Comment: Ok, where can i share the details?

Answer (score 0):

While creating child products there is an option to select a website look **Product in Websites** tab and then save the product see attachment:
[image]

Comment: Hello, i have done this properly, still the issue is coming

Comment: Did you reindex your website?

Comment: yes, hundreds of times

Comment: My email "nayem323@gmail.com"